# Javascript Windows 8 Read File From Folder, Return String

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I am simply trying to read a file from the roaming folder of a windows 8 app, and return a string. console.log(text) is printing the correct string, but I am obviously either not understanding promises and the delay or am messing up the javascript. str is undefined.

```
var getJsonString = function () {
    var jsonText;
    roamingFolder.getFileAsync(fileName)
            .then(function (file) {
                return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file);
            }).done(function (text) {
               //Printing Correct String
                console.log(text);
                jsonText = text;
            });
    return jsonText;
}

var str = getJsonString();
console.log(str);
```

I saw the MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465123, but still confused. Anybody have an idea?

Edit: Actually is there a better way to store a JSON string in the Roaming Folder? Right now I am just creating and using a text File.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I pull that string out to turn into JSON object for manipulation in program? I'm reading about promise objects now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it...

```
var getJsonStringAsync = function() {
    return roamingFolder.getFileAsync("myData.json")
        .then(function(file) {
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file);
        });
};

getJsonStringAsync().then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

See how your getJsonStringAsync function is now returning the results of the .then() function? That .then() function returns a Promise. I've renamed your function adding the Async suffix because it's now an asynchronous function and that's the convention.

Now anytime you use that function, you call it and use a .then() (or .done()) and specify a function whose parameter is the data that the promise is delivering you.

Hope this helps. You can check out [codefoster.com/using-promises](http://codefoster.com/using-promises) for some more information and the Promises demo that I have in my codeSHOW app ([on codeplex](http://codeshow.codeplex.com) and [in the Windows Store](http://aka.ms/codeshowapp)) might help you with the concept as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy! I got it working the way I needed and just downloaded your app since your obviously a good teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is **asynchronous**.  The `done()` callback happens some time after the rest of the function finishes.

You need to return a promise.